# RU Usage High for simple Mongo API $group Operation in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

We're attempting to migrate from a MongoDB to CosmosDB using the Mongo API.  In performance testing, we've noticed that a simple count operation on a Collection results in extremely high RU usage.  After removing the $group operation, **The RU usage drops from 8,586.56 to 11.39**.  Both executions also used the same indexes in the `$match` phase of the operation.  Would like to know why there's such a huge difference.  Is this a performance problem with CosmosDB?

In the code, we're simply executing a `collection.countDocuments(whereQuery)` which the MongoAPI is converting to:

```
{ 'aggregate' : 'NewOffers', 'pipeline' : [{ '$match' : { 'statusCode' : { '$in' : [0.0] } } }, { '$group' : { '_id' : 1.0, 'n' : { '$sum' : 1.0 } } }]
```

QueryStats with $group:

```
{
    "command" : "db.runCommand({explain: { 'aggregate' : 'NewOffers', 'pipeline' : [{ '$match' : { 'statusCode' : { '$in' : [0.0] } } }, { '$group' : { '_id' : 1.0, 'n' : { '$sum' : 1.0 } } }], 'explain' : true, 'cursor' : { }, 'lsid' : { 'id' : CSUUID('9714164a-f211-4a8f-a885-4457f9edf257') }, '$readPreference' : { 'mode' : 'secondaryPreferred' }, '$db' : 'myDb' }})",
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "stage" : "$aggregateQuery",
            "timeInclusiveMS" : 361.1143,
            "timeExclusiveMS" : 0.0613,
            "in" : 1,
            "out" : 1,
            "dependency" : {
                "getNextPageCount" : 1,
                "count" : 2,
                "time" : 361.053,
                "bytes" : NumberLong(101)
            },
            "details" : {
                "database" : "myDb",
                "collection" : "NewOffers",
                "query" : {
                    "statusCode" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            0.0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "indexUsage" : {
                    "pathsIndexed" : {
                        "individualIndexes" : [ 
                            "statusCode"
                        ],
                        "compoundIndexes" : []
                    },
                    "pathsNotIndexed" : {
                        "individualIndexes" : [],
                        "compoundIndexes" : []
                    }
                },
                "aggregate" : {
                    "_id" : 1.0,
                    "n" : {
                        "$sum" : 1.0
                    }
                },
                "shardInformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "eadabacc-383a-4cd7-b5ce-6abe4f5ce577",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 333.0191,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 1,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 35590
                    }, 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "703bef9a-62a4-4fc7-bcbc-85e7a35b3741",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 333.8226,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 1,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 35660
                    }, 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "a182b7ba-0565-4461-8d45-ac6f45a84d4f",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE,2FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 343.3216,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 1,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 35741
                    }, 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "4ddd60d5-d3c9-44d4-bbb8-397b8c51bcfb",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[2FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD,FF) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 347.9444,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 1,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 35215
                    }
                ],
                "queryMetrics" : {
                    "retrievedDocumentCount" : 142206,
                    "retrievedDocumentSizeBytes" : 380079234,
                    "outputDocumentCount" : 4,
                    "outputDocumentSizeBytes" : 496,
                    "indexHitRatio" : 0.0,
                    "totalQueryExecutionTimeMS" : 1317.74,
                    "queryPreparationTimes" : {
                        "queryCompilationTimeMS" : 0.86,
                        "logicalPlanBuildTimeMS" : 0.21,
                        "physicalPlanBuildTimeMS" : 0.47,
                        "queryOptimizationTimeMS" : 0
                    },
                    "indexLookupTimeMS" : 0.59,
                    "documentLoadTimeMS" : 802.01,
                    "vmExecutionTimeMS" : 1315.04,
                    "runtimeExecutionTimes" : {
                        "queryEngineExecutionTimeMS" : 512.4,
                        "systemFunctionExecutionTimeMS" : 101.12,
                        "userDefinedFunctionExecutionTimeMS" : 0
                    },
                    "documentWriteTimeMS" : 0.04
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "estimatedDelayFromRateLimitingInMilliseconds" : 0.0,
    "retriedDueToRateLimiting" : false,
    "totalRequestCharge" : 8586.56,
    "continuation" : {
        "hasMore" : false
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Executions stats after removing the `$group` stage

```
{
    "command" : "db.runCommand({explain: { 'aggregate' : 'NewOffers', 'pipeline' : [{ '$match' : { 'statusCode' : { '$in' : [0.0] } } }], 'explain' : true, 'cursor' : { }, 'lsid' : { 'id' : CSUUID('9714164a-f211-4a8f-a885-4457f9edf257') }, '$readPreference' : { 'mode' : 'secondaryPreferred' }, '$db' : 'myDb' }})",
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "stage" : "$query",
            "timeInclusiveMS" : 76.5114,
            "timeExclusiveMS" : 76.5114,
            "in" : 101,
            "out" : 101,
            "dependency" : {
                "getNextPageCount" : 1,
                "count" : 1,
                "time" : 0.0,
                "bytes" : NumberLong(185745)
            },
            "details" : {
                "database" : "myDb",
                "collection" : "NewOffers",
                "query" : {
                    "statusCode" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            0.0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "indexUsage" : {
                    "pathsIndexed" : {
                        "individualIndexes" : [ 
                            "statusCode"
                        ],
                        "compoundIndexes" : []
                    },
                    "pathsNotIndexed" : {
                        "individualIndexes" : [],
                        "compoundIndexes" : []
                    }
                },
                "shardInformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "930a2e5b-68aa-49f7-b04b-6e7607d917db",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 29.7279,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 101,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 101
                    }, 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "5697fd05-f12f-4bb4-8c0d-377debe1f890",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 7.4769,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 101,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 101
                    }, 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "6a2733b2-1b25-4098-a50e-f6e53ac09398",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE,2FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 28.7704,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 101,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 101
                    }, 
                    {
                        "activityId" : "34913339-b43e-473e-a5bd-fdfc84eb88ff",
                        "shardKeyRangeId" : "[2FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD,FF) move next",
                        "durationMS" : 34.9221,
                        "preemptions" : 0,
                        "outputDocumentCount" : 101,
                        "retrievedDocumentCount" : 101
                    }
                ],
                "queryMetrics" : {
                    "retrievedDocumentCount" : 404,
                    "retrievedDocumentSizeBytes" : 1051338,
                    "outputDocumentCount" : 404,
                    "outputDocumentSizeBytes" : 706377,
                    "indexHitRatio" : 1.0,
                    "totalQueryExecutionTimeMS" : 18.86,
                    "queryPreparationTimes" : {
                        "queryCompilationTimeMS" : 0.24,
                        "logicalPlanBuildTimeMS" : 0.12,
                        "physicalPlanBuildTimeMS" : 0.43,
                        "queryOptimizationTimeMS" : 0
                    },
                    "indexLookupTimeMS" : 0.34,
                    "documentLoadTimeMS" : 2.54,
                    "vmExecutionTimeMS" : 16.4799,
                    "runtimeExecutionTimes" : {
                        "queryEngineExecutionTimeMS" : 0.7,
                        "systemFunctionExecutionTimeMS" : 0.36,
                        "userDefinedFunctionExecutionTimeMS" : 0
                    },
                    "documentWriteTimeMS" : 12.8999
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "estimatedDelayFromRateLimitingInMilliseconds" : 0.0,
    "retriedDueToRateLimiting" : false,
    "totalRequestCharge" : 11.39,
    "continuation" : {
        "hasMore" : true,
        "$comment" : "Command did not fully drain, to fully drain add explain option {\"executionStatistics\": true }."
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Any idea why `retrievedDocumentCount` differ so much in the 2 queryStats?

Comment: Good question.  I'm assuming this is because when I remove the $group stage, it doesn't need to scan over all of the documents as part of the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about the issues you're having. The collection.countDocuments() driver method inefficiencies is a known issue that's being fixed - as you saw with the very high retrievedDocumentCount in explain. As a workaround, the [collection.count()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) method will be far more efficient.